# Wrap arrows in a div : AnythingSlider

Tags: jquery, html, css, anythingslider

I need you quick help. I am using AnythingSlider. left right arrows should be in wrap in a div to meet design requirements so is there any way to wrap them in a div.

```
<span class="arrow back" style=""></span> 
<span class="arrow next" style=""></span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$('.arrow').wrapAll('<div /');
```

Comment: The result of your lastest edit is something like this

<div><span class="arrow back" style=""><a href="#"><span>&amp;laquo;</span></a></span><span class="arrow forward" style=""><a href="#"><span>&amp;raquo;</span></a></span><span class="arrow back" style=""><a href="#"><span>&amp;laquo;</span></a></span><span class="arrow forward" style=""><a href="#"><span>&amp;raquo;</span></a></span></div>

Comment: How come? Does it happens only after you are added this code>

Comment: Maybe you have more arrows on a page with same class.

Comment: @Monkviper how many are there on the page., Arrow combinations that is.

Comment: Ya I got the issue. Its works!

$('.slider-wrapper .arrow').wrapAll('<div class="anythingslider-arrows">');

Thanks you